# mkdir recursion with permissions

Tags: bash, scripting

It's a simple question, I'm writing a **bash script called from cron** grouping files in tar file and classifing into a dir structure.

These dir needs a special owner and permissions, and I call **mkdir** command thru **su**:

```
#!/bin/bash

... # shortened code

$PERMS=750
$DIR=/home/luser/0/01/012/0123
$OWNER=luser

... # shortened code

su -c "mkdir -m $PERMS -p $DIR" $OWNER
```

Output for **ll -R /home/luser/0**

```
/home/luser/0:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 luser luser 4096 Jan  7 18:13 01

/home/luser/0/01:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 luser luser 4096 Jan  7 18:13 012

/home/luser/0/01/012:
total 4
drwxr-x--- 2 luser luser 4096 Jan  7 18:13 0123

/home/luser/0/01/012/0123:
total 0
```

Only the deepest dir has permissions (750) setting rightly.

I don't know how deep it's the last directory and set permissions for all home's file it's too hard (too much files).

PS: I'm googled about that, but I find nothing.

Comment: Observe date creation's dirs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict the permissions on the parent directories via `umask`. Here is an example:

```
PERMS=750
UMASK=$(echo "$PERMS" | tr "01234567" "76543210")
DIR=/home/luser/0/01/012/0123
OWNER=luser

su -c "umask $UMASK; mkdir -m $PERMS -p $DIR" $OWNER
```

In action:

```
> PERMS=750
> UMASK=$(echo "$PERMS" | tr "01234567" "76543210")
> (umask $UMASK; mkdir -m $PERMS -p 1/2/3/4)
> ll -R .
.:
drwxr-x---  3 luser luser  4096 Jan  7 1:38 1/

./1:
drwxr-x--- 3 luser luser 4096 Jan  7 1:38 2/

./1/2:
drwxr-x--- 3 luser luser 4096 Jan  7 1:38 3/

./1/2/3:
drwxr-x--- 2 luser luser 4096 Jan  7 1:38 4/
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a great solution but now I have two question: 1.- Can I remove **-m** parameter on mkdir? 2.- Why then mkdir have **-m** parameter? Only for the last dir?

Comment: It seems like a potential bug to me that `-m` doesn't apply to all directories created. I suppose it still has some use without `-p`, though you could always get the same effect by changing `umask` first. `umask` is persistent though, while `-m` would only affect the directory created by this command.